# Ignoring lines while comparing files using Python

Tags: python

I am having two text files which I want to compare using Python. Both of these files are having Date in their header. So, i want to ignore this line while comparison as it will always vary and should not be treated as difference.

**File1**

```
Date : 04/29/2013
Some Text
More Text
....
```

**File2**

```
Date : 04/28/2013
Some Text
More Text
....
```

I have tried comparing them using `filecmp` module, but that doesn't supports any argument to ignore any pattern. Is there any other module which can be used for this purpose. I tried using `difflib` but was not successfull. Moreover, I just want whether there is difference b/w files as `True or False`, `difflib` was printing all the lines even if there was no difference `using whitespace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`itertools.ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) (or builtin `filter` in Python 3)

> `itertools.ifilter(predicate, iterable)`

Your predicate should be a function, returning `False` for lines you want to ignore.
eg.

```
def predicate(line):
    if 'something' in line:
        return False # ignore it
    return True
```

Then use it on your file object. `fin = ifilter(predicate, fin)`

Then just use something like

```
from itertools import izip, ifilter # on Python 3 instead use builtin zip and filter
f1 = ifilter(predicate, f1)
f2 = ifilter(predicate, f2)

all(x == y for x, y in izip(f1, f2))
```

You don't need `difflib` unless you want to see what the differences were, and since you have tried `filecmp` I assume you only want to know whether there were difference or not. Unfortunately, `filecmp` only works with the filenames.

Also for skipping the first line of each file just use `itertools.islice(fin, 1, None)`

```
from itertools import islice, izip

def predicate(line):
    ''' you can add other general checks in here '''
    if line.startswith('Date'):
        return False # ignore it
    return True

with open('File1.txt') as f1, open('File2.txt') as f2:
    f1 = ifilter(predicate, f1)
    f2 = ifilter(predicate, f2)
    print(all(x == y for x, y in izip(f1, f2)))
```

---

```
>>> True
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting error. Can you please correct me if I am doing something wrong `>>> fo1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
>>> fo2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
>>> f1 = ifilter("Date", fo1)
>>> f2 = ifilter("Date", fo2)
>>> all(x == y for x, y in izip(f1, f2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: @sarbjit `predicate` should be a function, I updated my answer to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you know this date is always on the first line and you copy the lines in a list of strings you just can remove the first line by writing lines[1:]

Added after comment:

Probably it's best to use ifilter in the other solution.
If the files are different you have to iterate through them (using two indices, one for each file) and skip lines that contain one of the keywords.

Comment: Not ideal if large... use itertools.islice (fh,1, None) and iterate over that - is more generic and saves memory

Comment: Well, in most of the files date will be varying and is usually on first line. But my some of the files are having other keywords which will vary and can be anywhere in the file. So, I am looking for a more generic solution that will work for every case.