# How to do a diff in Python of two text files and ignore white space and blank lines?

Tags: python, diff

I can successfully compare two files using the Gnu `diff` command and the switch: `--ignore-all-space`.

I would now like to do the same in Python, but have found nothing that works.  I have read other articles in StackOverflow suggesting how, but none of them work.

I don't think people actually try things themselves to prove that a suggestion will work before posting.

---

If anyone has successfully done a diff on two files ignoring white space/blank lines in Python, please post, it would be most helpful to me and a number of others.

In python, I am importing `from filecmp import cmp`, and using this line:

`is_match = cmp(file1, file2)`

Comment: Can you provide links to the other SO articles that didn't work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring lines while comparing files using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275402/ignoring-lines-while-comparing-files-using-python)

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I don 't think that question will apply here.  It discusses ignoring lines containing particular content, not blank lines.

Comment: If white space is the only difference between the two files, then you should be able to read both files into memory as strings, and then apply a regular expression to each that replaces groups of whitespace with a single space.  Once you have done this, it should work to compare the two strings using `==`.

Comment: @Steve what's the difference? The content is.... nothing. The accepted answer is actually quite general and the predicate function in this case here can simply be `return bool(line.strip())`... Meaning empty lines will return `False` and be ignored. Your `re` method is highly inefficient especially if the files are very big

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I've taken another look at that question/answer, and I still don't see that it applies here.  The example uses `==` to compare lines, and the only interesting bit is that it filters out certain lines that are assumed to be different...specifically, lines that start with "Date".  For two files to be considered equal, any pairs of lines that do not start with "Date" have to be identical.  If one line has the addition of even a single space, the two files will be considered different.  Also, the files are compared line by line, so any difference in line breaks results in "not equal".

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how to use a a regular expression and `strip` to conform two texts containing only differences in whitespace so that they can be compared:

```
text1 = """now is        the
time
for
all             good men to come to
the aid         of their country
"""

text2 = """now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"""

import re

if (text1 == text2):
    print("YES!!!!")

text1 = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text1).strip()
text2 = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text2).strip()

print(text1)
print(text2)

if (text1 == text2):
    print("YES!!!!")
```

Result:

```
now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country
now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country
YES!!!!
```

All you need to do to use this technique is read each file's contents into a string, as represented here by `text1` and `text2`.

UPDATE: This method does use an appreciable amount of memory as each file has to be fully read into memory.  But if line endings are to be ignored in doing the comparison, then I'm not sure how else you'd accomplish the task without a lot of trickery involving fancy buffering of portions of each text in memory. But "appreciable" doesn't necessarily mean "worth worrying about" here.  Using this technique for files of even multiple megabytes in size should not be a problem.  I expect that most cases would involve much smaller text files.  There will certainly be cases where this technique needs to be replaced by something more complex because memory efficiency is a true concern.

If you can assume that the lines of the two files match up, and any difference between the two files is only at a per-line level, then you can iterate over the two files and compare them line by line, dropping the memory requirement to almost zero.  You can still use the technique shown here to compare each individual line.

As a test, I used an online Lorum Ipsum generator to produce this file:

```
> ls -l /tmp/t1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  wheel  8430006 Jan 18 12:29 /tmp/t1.txt
```

I tested the described technique with two copies of this 8+MB file.  When I ran it, I the time it took to read and compare the two files was noticeable, but it was under a second.  I don't know if performing this task in another way could avoid any of these few hundreds of milliseconds of execution time.

Comment: This is all good and well for these example strings, but if you have two very big files this is ***highly*** inefficient, saving the two contents to a string, manipulating them and then comparing them...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I disagree that there is significant inefficiency here.  Also, I don't think there's any way around bringing the files into memory without a lot of trickery, assuming that "ignore white space" means that the two texts can be broken up differently in terms of what appears on each line. Comparing line by line just doesn't work in that case.  This method does use a lot of memory, but memory is relatively plentiful these days. I bet we all have at least 8GB in our machines.  I would have no hesitation in using this algorithm to compare files that are even a few 10s of megabytes in size.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - see the additions to my answer.  They should address both the appropriateness of the line-by-line technique you pointed readers to, as well as the issues of efficiency and memory usage.